# How can compare suggestion models with different performances?

Tags: predictive-models, model-selection, binary-data

I have 4 class binary classification models. That models identify which class a particular  students is suitable for.

For example, we have `user 1` and 4 classes recommendation model.

Models were identify how this user would like to take its class.

By reading `user 1`'s personal profile data (features), model A, B, C, D predicts each class' fitness. Binary classification threshold were all 50%.

- `model A`: 77%, True
- `model B`: 65%, True
- `model C`: 33%, False
- `model D`: 88%, True

Based on this result, system recommends class `A, B, and C` to `user 1`.

However, models' performance were all different. Each model may have different F1-score, for example, `model A`: 77%, `model B`: 64%, `model C`: 81%, and `model D`: 55%.

How can we measure each recommendation score rationally, based on models' F1 score?

`I also had thought that some recommender system might works, however recommendation algorithms were limit to utilize user's profile.`

Comment: Please provide more details. How are these mixed effects models ?

Comment: @RobertLong those models were basic Forest-Based binary models e.g. random forest. Based on those models, teacher make decision that which course were better-fitting for users

Comment: OK no problem. So they're notning to do with Mixed Models ?

Comment: @RobertLong what I've faced concern is how we trust those binary models were concurrent. For example, model A decide class A's recommendation, and model B decide class B's recommendation. When model A and B's F1 score is 80%, 60% each, and they predict one user's preference that [0.72, 0.90] each (model A predicts 72% certainty and model B predicts 90% certainty that one user likes class A and B). Then how much we trust it's result? Since model A's F1 is higher then B, can we trust 72% certainty were better then 90% certainty of model B?

Comment: While I concerned with this, I found a keword that `multilabel classification`. This also good idea to solve this issue.